# formatting with spreadsheet gem not working

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet

I have spreadsheet that looks like the following as a CSV but is saved as an XLS file:

```
'foo', 'bar', ''
'', '', ''
```

I run the following ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spreadsheet'

t = Spreadsheet.open 'test.xls'
t.worksheet(0).row(0)[2] = 'qux'

format = Spreadsheet::Format.new :color=> :blue, :pattern_fg_color => :yellow, :pattern => 1
t.worksheet(0).row(0).set_format(2, format)

t.write('test_out.xls')
```

The new file looks like:

```
'foo', 'bar', 'qux'
'', '', ''
```

but nothing is colored.  Why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ruby, but with other programming platforms there is no row 0 in Excel. Try switching `row(0)` to `row(1)`

Comment: Joseph - The 'qux' line works with row(0)

Comment: this is clearly documented in the api for the spreadsheet gem (the library I'm using) here: http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html

The fact that I was able to write 'qux' in the first row of the sheet successfully strongly suggests that will not help.

Comment: @joseph4tw: In ruby, it starts with `0` :)

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730112/ruby-spreadsheet-row-background-color) thread shows that what you have should work... provided it is not a csv file. DISCLAIMER: I have never worked with Ruby (or any of her friends or sisters :P)

Comment: @PortlandRunner and Siddharth, thanks guys! "The more you know" :)

Comment: @olleicua: Did u check the link that I gave in my previous comment?

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes, thank you. This is the first I've seen anything use Rows as 0 based, which is a nice touch to be honest. I had plenty of issues remembering that for a while.

Comment: @joseph4tw: My apologies. My last comment was meant for `olleicua` Amended it. Got confused between you two..

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yep that's what I was going off of.  It is a .xls file.  It's supposed to work but its not.  Is it possible that this is a limitation of the .xls format?